# How to recreate the intro guitar sound of Rhythm of Love - Plain White T's?

Tags: guitar

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWiwuiT58Yc)

I'm not sure, but is that palm muting?

At 0:09-0:13, it doesn't look like he was palm muting.

If it is palm muting, is it just practice I'm lacking why I can't seem to reproduce it well?

Comment: Normally I trust my ears a lot more than my eyes when it comes to music. If palm muting sounds right then it is at least close enough for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

It sounded like palm muting, but

has a live version (@1:00) and the strumming is picked and it is muffled, so, I am guessing there is a pedal or massive EQ shelving.

--

That is palm muting (and probably finger strumming), but bear in mind it is a produced version where they can filter it, compress it, and EQ/volume duck it massively.

Comment: The guy singing in the blue shirt stage right (left side from the audience perspective) is **clearly** palm muting.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Both acoustic guitarist and the electric guitarist are ALL palm muting quite a bit in this vid.

Answer (score 0):

That sound can definitely be achieved just with palm muting. Practice, practice practice. :)